# I'd like to play a video with vlc using the 'open with' option

Tags: windows-10, batch, vlc-media-player

I'm on Windows 10 and have been using VLC for a long time to play movies/series via url.
Usually, I draw the url to the VLC window and it will play it, but I wanted to make it easier for me to play them and just draw them to a batch file to play the url. I'm having trouble doing that though.

I know the command to play the url is simply

`vlc <url>`

but as I said I wanted to use the 'open with' option to play the url and when I  drew in the url it wouldn't even open. It works perfectly fine when the url is added but I don't know how to add it to a batch file when using 'open with'.

Answer (score 1):

The path of the file dropped on a batch file is returned as a normal `%1` argument.

Example :

```
program.exe "%~1"
```

Use `%*` when dropping multiple files:

```
for %%a in (%*) do echo received [%%a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Shortcut** to easily pass the **URL** from your **`Clipboard`** to  **VLC** open it, with just one **click**, or using one **Shortcut Key**

**1.** Create one shortcut to **`PowerShell.exe`**:

```bat
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

**2.** Add the following command to PowerShell Shortcut:

```bat
 -nop -c "$url=Get-ClipBoard; $vlc=start-Process -FilePath "vlc" -ArgumentList $url,-f,vlc://quit"
```

**3.** Copy URL (by **<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>**) and then the Click on your shortcut or use ShortCut Key if set:

---

**Obs.: 1** If needed, adjust the command for keep VLC open after playing the URL,
just remove auto quit argument:  <strike>**`,vlc://quit`**</strike>

```bat
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nop -c "$url=Get-ClipBoard; $vlc=start-Process -FilePath "vlc" -ArgumentList $url,-f"
```

**Obs.: 2** Set your **Shortcut key** to *Run*, and set to *Start** in **Minimized** windows.

[image]